# Fitting a student t distribution in R using fitdistr() yields error “non-finite finite-difference value”

Tags: r, runtime-error, data-fitting

Reproducable example which will give the mentioned error code every time is:
(Note that even without set.seed, the error comes up every time)

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(seed = 1)
data<-rnorm(n = 10000,mean = 0.0002,sd = 0.001)
fitdistr(x = data,densfun = "t")
```

The error message is:

```
Error in stats::optim(x = c(-0.000426453810742332,       0.000383643324222082,  : 
non-finite finite-difference value [2]
In addition: Warning message:
In log(s) : NaNs produced
```

The problem is the "non-finite finite-difference value". Fitdistr does not give me a result.

My knowledge: 
I researched and apparently this could mean that a parameter is negative during the iteration. And that the solution could be to provide a better or at least different starting value. But I could not figure out how to do this and I am not sure if this is the issue.

MY QUESTION:
a) Why do I get this error message 
and 
b)how can I fix it in R, so that I can fit the student-t distribution to my normally distributed data?

Comment: This has not much to do with R, check out this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution), and more particularly the link between variance and the parameter nu. You will see that having data with such a small variance does not go well with the computation of nu. This is different when you have a non-centrality parameter, but still gives you an idea of why it does not work.

Comment: Also, I think this would fit better in http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @VincentGuillemot : I read your suggested page. From what I understand, if fitdistr() would assume a standard t distribution, then the variance has to be greater than 1. (Because of Var=v/(v-2) for the standard t) But for the non-standard t (and this is what fitdistr() assumes, since it gives values for m and s), the Variance can be smaller than 1 with the respective value for s. So why does the problem occur, once the variance of the normal data is “to small”? (Note that if data~N(mu, sd=0.01) the fitting works. But if data~N(mu, sd=0.001), the error pops up.)