# fitdistr from MASS library gives warnings when fitting t-distribution

Tags: r, optimization, statistics, distribution, mle

I'm trying to reproduce the following example from David Ruppert's "Statistics and Data Analysis for Financial Engineering", which fits Students t-distribution to historical risk free rate:

```
library(MASS)
data(Capm, package = "Ecdat")
x <-  Capm$rf
fitt <- fitdistr(x,"t", start = list(m=mean(x),s=sd(x)), df=3)
as.numeric(fitt$estimate)
0.437310595161651 0.152205764779349
```

The output is accompanied by the following Warnings message:

Warning message:

```
In log(s): NaNs producedWarning message:
In log(s): NaNs producedWarning message:
In log(s): NaNs producedWarning message:
In log(s): NaNs producedWarning message:
In log(s): NaNs producedWarning message:
In log(s): NaNs producedWarning message:
In log(s): NaNs producedWarning message:
In log(s): NaNs producedWarning message:
In log(s): NaNs produced
```

It appears from the R's help file that `MASS::fitdistr` uses maximum-likelihood for finding optimal parameters. However, when I do optimization manually (same book), all goes smoothly and there is no warnings:

```
library(fGarch)
loglik_t <- function(beta) {sum( - dt((x - beta[1]) / beta[2],
                                      beta[3], log = TRUE) + log(beta[2]) )}

start <- c(mean(x), sd(x), 5)
lower <- c(-1, 0.001, 1)
fit_t <- optim(start, loglik_t, hessian = T, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = lower)
fit_t$par
0.44232633269102 0.163306955396773 4.12343777572566
```

The fitted parameters are within acceptable standard errors, and, in addition to mean and sd I have gotten `df`.

Can somebody advise me please:

1. Why `MASS::fitdistr` produces warnings whereas optimization via `fGarch::optim` succeeds without a warning?
2. Why there is no `df` in `MASS::fitdistr` output?
3. Is there a way to run `MASS:fitdistr` on this data without a warning and get `df`?

Disclaimer:

a similar question was asked couple of times without an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073997/fitting-a-student-t-distribution-in-r-using-fitdistr-yields-error-non-finite) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072690/fitting-a-student-t-distribution-in-r-using-fitdistr-yields-error-non-finite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the `lower` argument to the function `fitdistr` which leads it to make a search in positive and negative domain. By passing the `lower` argument to function

```
fitt <- fitdistr(x,"t", start = list(m=mean(x),s=sd(x)), df=3, lower=c(-1, 0.001))
```

you get no NaNs -as you did in your manual optimisation.

EDIT:

```
fitt <- fitdistr(x,"t", start = list(m=mean(x),s=sd(x),df=3),lower=c(-1, 0.001,1))
```

returns non-integer degrees of freedom result. However, I guess, the rounded value of it, which is `round(fitt$estimate['df'],0)` can be used for fitted degrees of freedom parameter.

Comment: Thanks, warnings have disappeared! What about getting `df`?

Comment: `fitt <- fitdistr(x,"t", start = list(m=mean(x),s=sd(x), df=3), lower=c(-1, 0.01))` but it returns non-integer `df`result. Maybe it can help?